# Problems exporting custom textures in PS1 style

Tags: texturing, uv, unity

I watched some PS1 graphics tutorials and tried to create similar textures from low quality images. I textured practically every part of each face.

[image]

Is there any way I can create a UV map from my selections, or anything I can do to import the texture into Unity? I am not quite sure what to do.

[This is the tutorial I was watching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMplVXdI26M) and he seems to manage to get them into Unity using the same method, this video might just be for educational blender purposes though, I'm not sure.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Hello and welcome. it is best to add information into your original post, rather than post it in comments, where it can be easily missed

Comment: Seems like a question about Unity, not Blender. Or am I missing something? Are you asking how to export a texture and model? Textures can simply be saved from image editor and models can be exported via File - > Export menu.

Comment: Not sure if this is the question. But if this is a game model, I would create a new, clean UV map. That is, no overlapping UV islands except for mirroring and shared textures. Then you can bake the textures using the [new UV map](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/uv_map.html) to a new texture image. Maybe [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ff1IHpevXw&list=PLn3ukorJv4vu4aF4bbDA9GeX_puW7sKdE&index=3) helps.